# why is this closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

Today I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474545/famous-riddles-of-nine-9s) on the parent site.

Soon enough users started to close it as off-topic. I tried to find out the reason why by commenting there, many agreed that it's on-topic.

I am very much interested to know, why is it closed? If it is on-topic, could it be re-opened?

I did get my answer, but I don't think it benefits future readers to keep this question marked "closed as off-topic".

Answer (score 2):

To me the original question did look more like a math question than a programming questiong, so I'd guess that's why most people closed it. However, the addition of *How can I solve this riddle programatically? Could someone help me with some pseudo code or something?* combined with your explanations in the comments is enough to make me vote to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating here, but perhaps to some people it may have looked like you were trying to get them to do a homework problem for you.

Comment: Do you support re-opening it ?

Comment: @Philando Gullible It's kind of a moot point now, isn't it? There's already an answer with several upvotes which you've marked as accepted. What would be the purpose of reopening it?

Comment: Someone might come across the question in a years time with a much better answer, if it's closed they can't answer it.

Comment: @ho1 Good point.